# Error when saving in Sitecore Backend in the Core Database

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

After updating our Sitecore 6.3 to 6.6 we are facing the problem that when we want to save an item in the Core DB, this error message comes up:

```
[NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.]


Sitecore.Intranet.FrontendEditing.FrontendEditor.IsAutoVersioningEnabledForItem(Item item) +69
   Sitecore.Intranet.Pipelines.SaveUI.AddNewVersion.Process(SaveArgs args) +515

[TargetInvocationException: Ein Aufrufziel hat einen Ausnahmefehler verursacht.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct&amp; sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks) +1255
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +38
   Sitecore.Pipelines.Processor.Invoke(PipelineArgs args) +318
   Sitecore.Nexus.Pipelines.NexusPipelineApi.Resume(PipelineArgs args, Pipeline pipeline) +330
   Sitecore.Pipelines.Pipeline.DoStart(PipelineArgs args) +208
   Sitecore.Pipelines.Pipeline.Start(PipelineArgs args, Boolean atomic) +182
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.RunPipelines() +280
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +530
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +108
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3394



[NullReferenceException]: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
   bei Sitecore.Intranet.FrontendEditing.FrontendEditor.IsAutoVersioningEnabledForItem(Item item)
   bei Sitecore.Intranet.Pipelines.SaveUI.AddNewVersion.Process(SaveArgs args)
[TargetInvocationException]: Ein Aufrufziel hat einen Ausnahmefehler verursacht.
   bei System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   bei Sitecore.Pipelines.Processor.Invoke(PipelineArgs args)
   bei Sitecore.Nexus.Pipelines.NexusPipelineApi.Resume(PipelineArgs args, Pipeline pipeline)
   bei Sitecore.Pipelines.Pipeline.DoStart(PipelineArgs args)
   bei Sitecore.Pipelines.Pipeline.Start(PipelineArgs args, Boolean atomic)
   bei Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.RunPipelines()
   bei Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
   bei Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
   bei System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   bei System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
[HttpUnhandledException]: Eine Ausnahme vom Typ &quot;System.Web.HttpUnhandledException&quot; wurde ausgel&#246;st.
   bei System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   bei System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   bei System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   bei System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   bei System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   bei ASP.sitecore_shell_applications_content_manager_default_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0a348ed6\6269aa05\App_Web_x1rqdwhm.1.cs:Zeile 0.
   bei System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   bei System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Saving items in the Master DB works fine. We made the necessary config files changes. Backend and the Website are working fine.

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4):

Looking at your stack trace - exception is thrown by the `Sitecore.Intranet.FrontendEditing.FrontendEditor` class. This class is from **Sitecore Intranet** module.

The last version of **Sitecore Intranet** module which contains this class is **Sitecore Intranet 3.3** (which supports **Sitecore 6.3**).

This class no longer exists in **Sitecore Intranet 4.0** (which supports **Sitecore 6.6**).

You should update **Sitecore Intranet** module to [**4.0** version](https://sdn.sitecore.net/Resources/Sitecore%20Intranet%204/Sitecore%20Intranet%204,-d-,0/Sitecore%20Intranet.aspx)

---

**EDIT:**

[Release History of Sitecore Intranet](https://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20Intranet/Sitecore%20Intranet%204,-d-,0/Release%20Notes/Release%20History.aspx) says:

> **June 20, 2013**
>
> The Sitecore Intranet Platform - SIP v4.0 rev.130523 released on May 23, 2013.
>
> Tested with Sitecore CMS 6.6. rev. 130529  (Update-6) released on June 6, 2013.
>
> **Compatibility**
>
> This release only runs on Sitecore 6.6 and DMS 6.6.

---

**EDIT 2:**

You can try to create a class that will inherit from `Sitecore.Intranet.Pipelines.SaveUI.AddNewVersion` and catch this exception. It should not be executed for `core` database anyway.

Remember to register your new class **instead** of original `AddNewVersion`:

```xml
    <!-- processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Intranet.Pipelines.SaveUI.AddNewVersion, Sitecore.Intranet" / -->
    <processor mode="on" type="My.Assembly.Namespace.AddNewVersion, My.Assembly.Namespace" />
```

```cs
namespace My.Assembly.Namespace
{
    public class AddNewVersion : Sitecore.Intranet.Pipelines.SaveUI.AddNewVersion
    {
        public new void Process(Sitecore.Pipelines.Save.SaveArgs args)
        {
            try
            {
                base.Process(args);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Log.Error("Exception in AddNewVersion.Process", exc, this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Really? As far as I understand SIP 4.0 requires min. Sitecore 7.0.

Comment: According to Release History of SIP, SIP 4.0 is compatible with Sitecore 6.6. See edited answer.

Comment: I just checked and updating to SIP 4.0 is not an option, because when updating to 4.0, a lot of functions in the Sitecore.Intranet.dll are removed, which our project needs.

Comment: According to release history, SIP 3.3 is not compatible with Sitecore 6.6. Contact with Sitecore Support to get answers on missing functions in SIP 4.0.

Comment: We are running SIP 3.2. And according to Sitecore it is compatible with Sitecore 6.6.

Comment: See **Edit 2** in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at that.